# Web2py disable session cookies per controller

Tags: session-cookies, web2py

Is there a way to not save session ids & the session cookie in web2py on a per-controller level? `global_settings.web2py_disable_session = True` will do it for the whole site, but I want some pages to retain sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use the parameter-based rewrite system, you can disable sessions based on routing using the pattern-based rewrite system. In the `routes.py` file, you would do something like this:

```
routes_in = [
    ('/myapp/default/$anything', '/myapp/default/$anything', 
     dict(web2py_disable_session=True))
]
```

The optional third element of a `routes_in` tuple is a dictionary, which will be used to update `request.env`. The above will add `web2py_disable_session=True` to `request.env` only for routes starting with `/myapp/default/` (setting `global_settings.web2py_disable_session=True`, on the other hand, will add `web2py_disable_session=True` to `request.env` for all requests).

Alternatively, you can simply call `session.forget(response)` in any controller or action that does not need the session (or conditionally in a model file depending on the requested path). If no session cookie or file have yet been created, this will prevent their creation. Although simpler, this method is slightly less efficient than the above, as it will still result in the session initialization code running on every request.

One final alternative would be to create a custom WSGI application function in the WSGI handler file that conditionally adds `web2py_disable_session=True` to the WSGI environment dictionary depending on the requested route. Then pass the modified environment dictionary to `gluon.main.wsgibase`.

Comment: I am actually using the parameter-based rewrites - it sounds like I would have to switch to pattern-based to get anything like this working then?